# php loop getting values from second table

Tags: php, mysqli

I have two tables: `tableA` and `tableB` I want to print the column value of `tableB`.
My table structure is below:

```
Table A 
-id--------Name-----
 1          A
 2          B
 3          C
 4          D
--------------------


Table B

tableB_id-----------tableA_id-------------value-------
1                      1                    68
2                      1                    94
3                      1                    97
4                      1                    88
5                      1                    93
6                      1                    69
7                      1                    95
8                      2                    68
9                      2                    94
10                     3                    68
11                     4                    68
12                     4                    95
------------------------------------------------------
```

Final output needs to be as below with values comma separated

```
id------Name----------value-----------------------------------------
 1        A        68,94,97,88,93,69,95
 2        B        68,94
 3        C        68
 4        D        68,95
```

---

I tried the below code:

Here for each id in the `tableA` there will be multiple `print_r($arr1)` commands represented as `FIRST`. In the code it is printing duplicate values, but the command reperesented as `SECOND` is getting the correct values.

My question is how I can avoid duplicate values in the `FIRST` code part

```
<?php
$rs = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM `tableA`  limit $offset,$rows");
$items = array();   
$a=0;
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_object($rs))
{ 
  $qry1 = mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT tableB.value FROM tableA ,tableB WHERE tableA.`tableA_id`=tableB.`tableA_id` AND tableA.`tableA_id`='".$row->id."'");    
  $i=0;   
  while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qry1))  
  {
    if($row2['id']=$row1->id)
    {
      $arr1 = $row2['value'];
    }
    print_r($arr1); // SECOND
    $i++;
  }   
  print_r($arr1); // FIRST
  array_push($items, $row1);
}
?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think GeoffK is on the right track with GROUP_CONCAT.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT tableA.id AS id,
       tableA.name AS name,
       GROUP_CONCAT( tableB.value ) AS value
FROM tableA
  JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.id = tableB.tableA_id
GROUP BY tableA.id
```

Comment: I used the query along with group  concat.The problem is the group_concat values have to be referenced to another table to get the name of the id ,thats why i want to avoid group_concat

Comment: Can you update your question to show a complete example of what you need, including this third table?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question correctly - but what I think you might be looking for is [GROUP_CONCAT](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/mysql-the-group_concat-function/)

Comment: Yes i can use GROUP_CONCAT but i may aafter i get comma separated,i need to refer one more table to get the name of the ids ..Is that possible ?